# What are the implications of destroying a socket after end()?

Tags: node.js, http

I am seeing scenarios where in case of a `clientError`, the client does not acknowledge FIN, i.e.

```js
httpServer.on('clientError', (error, socket) => {
    socket.write(stringifyHttpResponseMessage(400, {connection: 'close'}, 'OK'));

    socket.end();

    setTimeout(() => {
        // socket remains writable.
        // What is the risk of calling `socket.destroy()` here?

        socket.destroy();
    }, 1000);
});
```

As a result, a burst of client errors result in open sockets until the associated idle socket timeout is reached (which is quite high).

What are the implications of destroying a socket after `end()`?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. To solve this problem, I destroyed the socket after the response is written instead of ending the socket. Here's an example of what I did.

```js
httpServer.on('clientError', (error, socket) => {
  socket.write(stringifyHttpResponseMessage(400, {connection: 'close'}, 'OK'), 'utf8', () => {
    socket.destroy();
  });
});
```

It works as expected so far.